# Download layer from GeoServer

Tags: geoserver

I'm new about GeoServer. I want to download preview layer and data of the layer from GeoServer, how can I do that?

Comment: Make a WFS or WCS request

Answer (score 1):

you could create a wfs layer in GeoServer then load it in QGIS. Once it is loaded as a layer, you could save the layer as any format supported by QGIS.

More information about how to create a Web Feature Service (WFS) in GeoServer is available [here](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wfs/index.html)

I hope this helps.

[image]